# split one row into multiple record python

Tags: python

I have an input dataframe as follows

```
Class   Duration    StudentID   Age Startdate   Start Time  Enddate     End Time    TimeDifference
5th     XX          20002       5   04/12/2021  17:00:00    04/14/2021  20:00:00    3000
```

And I would like to split the same into three different rows based on the start and end date as follows.

```
Class   Duration    StudentID   Age     Startdate   Start Time  Enddate     End Time    TimeDifference
5th     XX          20002       5       04/12/2021  17:00:00    04/12/2021  23:59:59    360
5th     XX          20002       5       04/13/2021  0:00:00     04/13/2021  23:59:59    1440
5th     XX          20002       5       04/14/2021  0:00:00     04/14/2021  20:00:00    1200
```

I am trying with python. Please help.

[Input Output is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtN2E.jpg)

Comment: Looks quite tough, I would try this approach: calculate the number of rows coming from the initial one (eg number of days), the splitt the rows using [`pandas.Series.repeat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html). To finalize `Startdate` and `Enddate` values, you might need to [create a time series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html)

Comment: Can you provide some code showing the what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I get a slightly different value for 'Time Difference', but this is an approach you can tweak and and use.

**Step 1:**
You can start by using [`melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) with your `id_vars` being all your columns except your 'Startdate' and 'Enddate'.

**Step 2:**
Then you can set your `index` to be your StartEndDate column, created after melting your dataframe.

**Step 3:**
Then using [`reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) you can add the new row with your missing dates.

Lastly what's left is to calculate the time difference column and rearrange your dataframe to get to your final output.

I assume your dataframe is called `df`:

```
# Step 1
ids = [c for c in df.columns if c not in ['Startdate','Enddate']]
new = df.melt(id_vars=ids,value_name = 'StartEndDate').drop('variable',axis=1)
new.loc[new.StartEndDate.isin(df['Startdate'].tolist()),'Start Time'] = "00:00"

print(new)
  Class Duration  StudentID  Age Start Time End Time  TimeDifference  \
0   5th       XX      20002    5      00:00    20:00            3000   
1   5th       XX      20002    5      17:00    20:00            3000   

  StartEndDate  
0   04/12/2021  
1   04/14/2021  

# Step 2
new['StartEndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(new['StartEndDate']).dt.date
new.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(new.StartEndDate),inplace=True)

# Step 3
final = new.reindex(pd.date_range(new.index.min(),new.index.max()), method='ffill').reset_index()\
    .rename({'index':'Startdate'},axis=1).drop('StartEndDate',axis=1)
final['Enddate'] = final['Startdate']

final['TimeDifference'] = (final['End Time'].str[:2].astype(int) - final['Start Time'].str[:2].astype(int))*60
```

Prints:

```
final = final[['Class','Duration','StudentID','Age','Startdate','Start Time','Enddate','End Time','TimeDifference']]

   Class Duration  StudentID  Age  Startdate Start Time    Enddate End Time  \
0   5th       XX      20002    5 2021-04-12      00:00 2021-04-12    20:00   
1   5th       XX      20002    5 2021-04-13      00:00 2021-04-13    20:00   
2   5th       XX      20002    5 2021-04-14      17:00 2021-04-14    20:00   

   TimeDifference  
0            1200  
1            1200  
2             180
```

I think some information is missing from your question, so I would suggest running line by line and do the necessary adjustments to suit your task.

Comment: Thank you so much, but for me i am not able to re-index  for the last step. I am getting 
 ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me. df is the source data frame and df1 is the result.

cols = data.columns
df=data
df['ReportDate'] = [pd.date_range(x, y) for x , y in zip(df['Startdate'],df['Enddate'])]
df1 = df.explode('ReportDate')
df1.head()

df1['RptStart']=np.where(df1['ReportDate'] == df1['Startdate'],df1['StartTime'],datetime.time(00, 00, 00))

df1['RptEnd']=np.where(df1['Enddate'] == df1['ReportDate'],df1['EndTime'],datetime.time(23, 59, 59))

df1['StartDtTm']=df1.apply(lambda r : pd.datetime.combine(r['ReportDate'],r['RptStart']),1)
df1['EndDtTm']=df1.apply(lambda r : pd.datetime.combine(r['ReportDate'],r['RptEnd']),1)

df1['Duration']= round((df1['EndDtTm']-df1['StartDtTm']).astype('timedelta64[s]')/60)